# Doctrine 2 design pattern tips

Tags: design-patterns, doctrine-orm, entities

I'm trying to figure out the best way to define my entities in Doctrine 2, but no solution really feels right. I might be going at this from the wrong angle so pointers are very appreciated.

The problem is about defining entities for Users and one or more Profiles. Right now, I have the current setup:

**User**

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class User {
    use AutoIdentifiable; //Trait for auto-generating an @id.

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="UserProfile", mappedBy="user", cascade={"all"}, fetch="EAGER", orphanRemoval=TRUE)
     * @var UserProfile
     */
    protected $profiles;    
}
```

**UserProfile**

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("JOINED")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="discr", type="string")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({"personalprofile" = "PersonalProfile", "companyprofile" = "CompanyProfile"})
 */
abstract class UserProfile {
    use AutoIdentifiable;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="profiles", fetch="EAGER")
     * @var User
     */
    protected $user;
}
```

**PersonalProfile**

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class PersonalProfile extends UserProfile {
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(length=50)
     * @var String
     */
    protected $firstName;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(length=50)
     * @var String
     */
    protected $lastName;
}
```

**CompanyProfile**

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class CompanyProfile extends UserProfile {

    /**
     * @ORM\Column
     * @var String
     */
    protected $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(length=9)
     * @var String
     */
    protected $orgNr;
}
```

As you can see, one user can have one or more profiles containing very different information. If I decide to continue using this design, I will probably add more profiles later depending on which roles the user has. (For example, if a user has a personal blog they might have a BlogProfile containing a picture and some description of themselves.)

The problem is that it's very unwieldy to load and check for a specific profile, and users might even have combinations of profiles. (Ex: Personal+Blog)
It doesn't seem to be a great idea to just have a named reference to each specific profile either. I did check the Decorator pattern, but I'm not sure it would be a good fit.

**The questions are:**

1. Is there a design pattern I'm missing that is perfect for this type of structure?
2. Maybe there's even a better way to go about the entire problem?
3. Does anyone have experience with these type of data structures and can share some helpful tips?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't implemented it myself, but I think you may have a look at how ResolveTargetEntityListener is used in doctrine:

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/cookbook/resolve-target-entity-listener.html